# How to write a select query for MySQL having column with datatype Json?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to write a select query in MySQL and ruby on rails which find all the detail of a student having marks1=50;
Table looks like this:

```
TableName - Student
Name:        Type:
id           int
First Name   varchar(50)
Last  Name   varchar(50)
Class        varchar(50)
Marks        Json --- this has {marks1:<somevalue>,marks2:<somevalue>,marks3:<somevalue>,marks4:<somevalue>,marks5:<somevalue>}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your model named `Student` then query will be:

`Student.where("marks -> '$.marks1' = '50'")`

more info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @roman. It worked i was missing a "$." in my query.